# How do I change back to normal default view from user perspective view?

Tags: 3d-view

I don't know how to return to animating because it all disappeared when I hit <kbd>0</kbd> and it went to perspective view.

Comment: numpad 0 is used to enter camera view, numpad 5 is used to switch between perpective and orthogonal view

Answer (score 4):

Just hold middle mouse button and drag to rotate the view.

The <kbd>5</kbd> on your Numpad switches between perspective and orthographic view.

<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> switches into Camera view.

<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>  Front View

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> Bottom View

<kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> Right View

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> Left View

<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> Top View.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> Bottom View